# How do I ignore a pipe symbol at the front?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, grep

How do I ignore forward slash and space at the start of the line in regular expressions?

In the Example below, I need to ignore the pipe and space because I am using grep 
and awk

The actual command gives me

cmd

```
size=5.0G features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=active
| `- 3:0:0:3   sdh  8:112   active ready running    #Line 3
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled
  `- 4:0:0:3   sdl  8:176   active ready running    #Line 5
```

By doing this:

```
cmd | grep -E '[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+' | awk '{print $3}'
```

I was able to get the sdh, sdl. But the problem is, I need to ignore the '|' upfront, to make the Line 3 and Line 5 same. Please advise.

Edit 1
I need to get two information

1) the Number

```
3:0:0:3
4:0:0:3
```

2) Disk name

```
sdh
sdl
```

Comment: There's no slash in your example.

Comment: Sorry that is '|' not slash...... I dont know what it is....

Comment: Okay, I did not use the work pipe, since it might confuse.....

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Please give your expected output.

Comment: What is the command? It may have options that modify the format of the output.

Comment: the command is multipath -ll .....

Comment: [XYProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: Okay, I need to ignore the '|' pipe symbol and the space at the front,  so the input for awk becomes same.,....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than try to make each of your two lines have identical number of fields, just use the `-o` option of grep to only part of the line that matches your regular expression. Then you won't need the `awk` command at all.

```
cmd | grep -o -E '[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+'
```

Since you actually need more than just what was in your original question:

```
cmd | grep -E '[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+' | sed 's/^| //' | awk '{print $2, $3}'
```

Comment: Actually I need other informations in the line also....... like the disk name sdh/sdl etc etc.....

Comment: @howtechstuffworks and that's why we need to know what you're expecting as output.

Answer (score 2):

Do it all in `awk`:

```
gawk --re-interval '/[0-9:]{4}/ { sub("\\|", ""); print $2, $3 }'
```

See @CodeGnome's version for a more precise regex.

Comment: +1. I like your solution, but I'd add `awk --re-interval '/([[:digit:]]:){3,}[[:digit:]]/ { sub("\\|", ""); print $2, $3 }'` as a gawk alternative because it's a little more expressive.

Comment: Ah better, forgot about the quantifiers, will add it to my example.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably adjust your command to provide less cruft to your regular expression matcher. However, you can certainly do this with a Perl-compatible regular expression. For example:

```
$ pcregrep -o '((\d:){3}\d)\s+\S+' << 'EOF'
size=5.0G features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=active
| `- 3:0:0:3   sdh  8:112   active ready running    #Line 3
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled
  `- 4:0:0:3   sdl  8:176   active ready running    #Line 5
EOF

3:0:0:3   sdh
4:0:0:3   sdl
```

You can then split the two fields using IFS, awk, or some other mechanism before feeding it to your next step in the script.